# Grid Fill multiple areas

Tags: mesh, edit-mode, workflow

Hey there just wondering if there's a way to grid fill multiple edge areas at the same time, ie in this rough example I know I can grid fill these selected edges...

[image: Text]

but can I grid fill all these edges at the same time rather than having to do a second grid fill operation...

[image: Text]

The reason I ask is because I may have a lot of grid filling to do.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hey :). Grid fill probably won't work here. You need two edge loops, or Blender won't know how to fill it.

Comment: Actually I might look at trying out https://blendermarket.com/products/curves-to-mesh